Prove/disprove: $d(x, \phi(x)) \leq f(x) - f(\phi(x))$ implies $\phi$ is a contraction
According to Approach0, this question seems new.
There is a similar question, however in that question asked for a proof about a function, which satisfied the definition (see Problem), has a fix point. However a function, which has a fixed point, doesn't implies it is a contraction ($f(x)=x$).
Motivation: I am self-studying for my next semester math course. I did some past exam papers from that course (no solutions provided), then I met with this question, but I am not sure how to do.
Problem

Let $X$ be a complete metric space and $\phi: X \to X$ be continuous.
If exists a function $f: X \to [0, \infty)$ such that
$$d(x, \phi(x)) \leq f(x) - f(\phi(x)) \quad \text{for all } x \in X,$$Is $\phi$ necessarily a contraction?

My idea:
Definition of contraction: $\forall x,y\in X,\exists\alpha\in[0,1),d(\phi(x),\phi(y))\leq\alpha d(x,y)$.
$$\begin{align}
d(\phi(x),\phi(y))&\leq f(\phi(x))-f(\phi(y))=d(f(\phi(x)),f(\phi(y)))
\end{align}$$However, I don't know to how connect $d(f(\phi(x)),f(\phi(y)))$ with $f(x)-f(\phi(x))$.
Thus, I think the statement is false, I tried $X=[0,\infty)$, $\phi(x)=x-1$ which is not a contraction and $f(x)=x^2$. $$d(x,\phi(x))=d(x,x-1)=1,f(x)-f(\phi(x))=x^2-(x-1)^2=2x-1$$However it is not true that $1\leq2x-1$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$.
Thus, my question is if the statement is true, how can I continue? If the statement is false, is there an way to construct such counterexamples and can anyone please explain the intuition behind. Thank!

How about just the identity map $\phi(x) = x$? This is of course, not a contraction, but for every $x, d(x,\phi(x)) = 0 \le 0 = f(x) - f(\phi(x)),$ no matter what $f$ is.

Also, this is not relevant to the question, but in the proof attempt, you write $d( f(\phi(x)), f(\phi(y))).$ This doesn't make sense because the domain of $d$ is $X \times X,$ while $f(\cdot)$ is a positive real, so need not lie in $X$. It's worth being careful about such things, in general.

Thanks a lot! I might have over-complicated the counter-example when I am trying figure out the solution.

No, this is not even true if you allow for non-strict contractions. For example, $X = [0,1]$, and let $\phi(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) = x$. Since $\phi$ has two fixed points at $0$ and $1$, we can see that $\phi$ is not a contraction. Moreover $0 \leq x \leq 1$ implies that $d(x,\phi(x)) = x - x^2 = f(x) - f(\phi(x))$.
